# Is there a [straightforward] way to order results *first*, *then* group by another column, with SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, group-by, sql-order-by

I see that in an SQL query, the `GROUP BY` clause has to precede `ORDER BY`. Does this imply that ordering is done after grouping would have discarded identical rows?

Because I seem to need to order rows by a timestamp first, *then* discard the rows with identical timestamp. And I don't know how to accomplish this.

I am using MySQL 5.1.41.

Here is the definition of the table expressed with `create table`:

```
create table (
    A int,
    B timestamp
)
```

The data could be:

```
+-----+-----------------------+
|  A  |  B                    |
+-----+-----------------------+
|  1  |  today                |
|  1  |  yesterday            |
|  2  |  yesterday            |
|  2  |  tomorrow             |
+-----+-----------------------+
```

The results of the query on the above table, which I am after, would be:

```
+-----+-----------------------+
|  A  |  B                    |
+-----+-----------------------+
|  1  |  today                |
|  2  |  tomorrow             |
+-----+-----------------------+
```

Basically, I want the rows with the latest timestamp in column "B" (hence the mention of `ORDER BY`), and only one row for each value in column "A" (think `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`).

##### The actual problem behind the simplified example above:

In reality, I have two tables - `users` and `payment_receipts`:

```
create table users (
    phone_nr int(10) unsigned not null,
    primary key (phone_nr)
)

create table payment_receipts (
    phone_nr int(10) unsigned not null,
    payed_ts timestamp default current_timestamp not null,
    payed_until_ts timestamp not null,
    primary key (phone_nr, payed_ts, payed_until_ts)
)
```

The tables may include other columns but I omit these as irrelevant. Implementing a payment scheme, I have to send SMS to users across the cellular network, in periodic intervals depending on whether the payment is due or not. The payment is actualized when the SMS is sent as the recipient is taxed for it. I use the `payment_receipts` table to keep records of all payments done, i.e. for book-keeping. This is intended to model a real shop where both the buyer and the seller get a copy of the receipt of purchase, for reference. This table stores my (seller's) copy [of each receipt]. The customer's receipt is the received SMS itself. Each time an SMS is sent (and thus a payment is accomplished), the table is inserted a receipt record, stating who paid, when and "until when". To explain the latter, imagine a subscription service, but one which spans indefinitely until the user opt-out explicitly, at which point the corresponding user record is removed. A payment is made a month in advance, so as a rule, the difference between the `payed_ts` and `payed_until_ts` is 30 days worth of time.

I have a batch job that executes every day and needs to select a list of users that are due monthly payment as part of the automatic subscription renewal described above. To link this to the dummy example earlier, the phone number column `phone_nr` would be the column "A" and `payed_until_ts` would be column "B", but in reality there are two tables, which has to do with the following behaviour: when a user record is removed, the receipt must remain, for book-keeping. So not only do I need to group payments by date and discard all but the latest payment receipt date, I also need to watch out not to select receipts for which there no longer is a matching user record.

To solve the problem of selecting required records -- those that are due payment -- I need to find receipts with the latest `payed_until_ts` timestamp for each `phone_nr` (there may be several, obviously) and out of those records I further need to select only those phone numbers where `payed_until_ts` is earlier than the time the batch job executes. I then would send an SMS to each of these numbers, inserting a receipt record for each sent SMS, where `payed_ts` is `now()` and `payed_until_ts` is `now() + interval 30 days`.

But I can't seem to come up with the query required.

Comment: `The tables may include other rows`? Come again?

Comment: There should have been written 'columns', of course. I have corrected it. Thanks for spotting it out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Select a,b from (select a,b from table order by b) as c group by a;
```

Comment: @Vash, have you never heard of a subquery: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: @Vash please do! I want to get my head around this.

Comment: @amn, this is a valid mysql query. Not sure what breed of SQL you're using. Perhaps you should add which version of SQL you're using to this questions tags?

Comment: Actually, it looks like what I need. I use MySQL 5.1.41, and don't aim for SQL portability, at least not to a degree where I won't use this because of portability concerns. Just out of curiosity, is it possible to rewrite this query using join syntax?

Comment: @amn, you can write it using a join, but it might not be quicker because either way it involves temp tables. Updating my answer to include it...

Comment: @amn, forget the join version, it's too unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @amn @Meke Sherov & others

First error is that you are trying to display column B that is not aggregated and not in the GROUP BY clause... 

Second that sub select that you use works on Oracle and MySql byt in sql server doesn't, nevertheless this ordering is case is useless. The tables are sets so to understand this read about set theory.

Comment: @vash, Amn is using mysql and doesn't care about SQL server. Second, you don't need to only grab aggregate columns when doing a group by in mysql. Third, the ordering is useful to gaurantee that the group by will choose the lowest timestamp's row, as we all know group by uses the row it first encounters. Ordering first makes sure it encounter the lowest timestamps first for every case. Fourth, you don't need to read about set theory to see that my answer is valid and accomplishes the goals presented by @amn.

Comment: I can confirm that this works as described. I wish I could comprehend what you mean @Vash, I really do. But it works. Are you saying this will break in some scenarios? To me it actually looks really simple - the subquery results are returned ordered only on timestamps, and then grouping selects a row for each distinct `a`, with `b` always the earliest/latest (depending on `asc`/`desc`) timestamp from all timestamps with the same value in `a`. What's not to like? :-)

Comment: @amn, it will not break. Although I appreciated the discussion, all of vash's concerns seem to be based on SQL server, which you're not using.

Comment: @Mike Sherov - For my is something new, that You don't have to use any function or use for grouping. This because i've never work with MySql. In this case i assume the B i taken first form group A.. so if this possible in MySQL every thing as You sad has right place in that query. @amn No, if this is fine with one will be correct in every case for MySQL database engine. As Mike S. already sad my concerns came from that You do not specified at the beginning which db You are using, and my lack of knowledge in MySQL.

Comment: So what I ended up doing, largely derived from @Mike's answer:
`select users.phone_nr, p.payed_until_ts from users inner join (select * from (select phone_nr, payed_until_ts from payment_receipts order by payed_until_ts desc) as o group by phone_nr) as p using (phone_nr) where payed_until_ts < now()`. I have indexes in proper places, so the query is fast, and it pleases me that it is correct.

Comment: @amn, you can optimize this further: `select * from (select users.phone_nr as phone_nr, p.payed_until_ts as payed_until_ts from users inner join payment_receipts using (phone_nr) where payed_until_ts < now() order by payed_until_ts desc) as t group by phone_nr;` This will do the joining, ordering, and where in one pass, and then do the group by afterwards. I haven't tested it, and assuming there aren't syntax errors, it might be faster.

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, it is wrong because it uses a MySQL extension that is *explicitly* documented not to work.  The extension is the use of columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: i am using mysql 5.7.17 and its not working with my db.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, grouping is done first, and it affects a single `select` whereas ordering affects all the results from all `select` statements in a `union`, such as:

```
select a, 'max', max(b) from tbl group by a
union all select a, 'min', min(b) from tbl group by a
order by 1, 2
```

(using field numbers in `order by` since I couldn't be bothered to name my columns). Each `group by` affects only its `select`, the `order by` affects the combined result set.

It seems that what you're after can be achieved with:

```
select A, max(B) from tbl group by A
```

This uses the `max` aggregation function to basically do your pre-group ordering (it doesn't *actually* sort it in any decent DBMS, rather it will simply choose the maximum from an suitable index if available).

Comment: This though wouldn't gaurantee the whole row that contains the MAX(B), which I believe the asker wants. Is there any way to do that without the answer I provided?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @Mike. This gets the whole row. If you have _extra_ columns that you want pulled from the row with the highest `B` then, yes, you need another way, since you _have_ to use an aggregation function and it may result in a value from a different row. That way is a nightmare in standard SQL and should probably be left to a higher (i.e., application) layer.

Comment: @pax, yes it requires a subselec if you want other values from the row that has the max(b), which I agree is a nightmare (huge possible temp table). I would think though that doing it in the app. layer would be an even bigger nightmare :)

Comment: @Mike, I didn't understand what you mean. What's the meaning of to "guarantee the whole row"?

Comment: @amn, imagine you're table had a third column, "c", which had usernames. Now, if you did "select a,max(b),c from table group by a", you'd get the max timestamp, but the username from the lowest timestamp.

Comment: @paxdiablo You do have a very useful answer, and I have confirmed it works very well for me. The only caveat here is that one needs to be aware that this will NOT work (as mentioned by others) where there are other columns to be retrieved beside `a` and `max(b)`. Since I am planning to eventually select other columns as well, I will not use your solution. But wanted to say a big thank you nevertheless, as for certain scenarios it is perfectly valid!

Comment: No probs, @amn. My solution is fine for the question posed but, as you say, problematic if you want other columns from the same row.

Answer (score 2):

### According to your new rules (tested with PostgreSQL)

**Query You'd Want:**

```
SELECT    pr.phone_nr, pr.payed_ts, pr.payed_until_ts 
FROM      payment_receipts pr
JOIN      users
          ON (pr.phone_nr = users.phone_nr)
   JOIN      (select phone_nr, max(payed_until_ts) as payed_until_ts 
              from payment_receipts 
              group by phone_nr
             ) sub
             ON (    pr.phone_nr       = sub.phone_nr 
                 AND pr.payed_until_ts = sub.payed_until_ts)
ORDER BY  pr.phone_nr, pr.payed_ts, pr.payed_until_ts;
```

**Original Answer (with updates):**

```
CREATE TABLE foo (a NUMERIC, b TEXT, DATE);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES 
   (1,'a','2010-07-30'),
   (1,'b','2010-07-30'),
   (1,'c','2010-07-31'),
   (1,'d','2010-07-31'),
   (1,'a','2010-07-29'),
   (1,'c','2010-07-29'),
   (2,'a','2010-07-29'),
   (2,'a','2010-08-01');

-- table contents
SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY c,a,b;
 a | b |     c      
---+---+------------
 1 | a | 2010-07-29
 1 | c | 2010-07-29
 2 | a | 2010-07-29
 1 | a | 2010-07-30
 1 | b | 2010-07-30
 1 | c | 2010-07-31
 1 | d | 2010-07-31
 2 | a | 2010-08-01

-- The following solutions both retrieve records based on the latest date
--    they both return the same result set, solution 1 is faster, solution 2
--    is easier to read

-- Solution 1: 
SELECT    foo.a, foo.b, foo.c 
FROM      foo
JOIN      (select a, max(c) as c from foo group by a) bar
  ON      (foo.a=bar.a and foo.c=bar.c)
ORDER BY  foo.a, foo.b, foo.c;

-- Solution 2: 
SELECT    a, b, MAX(c) AS c 
FROM      foo main
GROUP BY  a, b
HAVING    MAX(c) = (select max(c) from foo sub where main.a=sub.a group by a)
ORDER BY  a, b;

 a | b |     c      
---+---+------------
 1 | c | 2010-07-31
 1 | d | 2010-07-31
 2 | a | 2010-08-01
(3 rows)
```

**Comment:**
`1` is returned twice because their are multiple `b` values.  This is acceptable (and advised).  Your data should never have this problem, because `c` is based on `b`'s value.

Comment: Yes, this works, although I don't need the final ordering of rows. Also, it exhibits the same problem as other solutions using `max` - if there are other columns to retrieve besides the `max` and `a`, I am not sure which row will return these.

Comment: @amn: could you be a little more descriptive in what you're trying to accomplish?  don't be afraid to make your example a little more explicit - SO is filled with programmers that perform all levels of programming. `group by`, groups on a set of keys to return a unique set of values. if you want to return more columns, include it in the `select` and `group by`

Comment: Hello, I have added a whole section with the actual problem, for your "pleasure" :-) Thank you for your time. Your update would not apply, because no two records with duplicate `a` may appear in the results.

Comment: I have to go to a wedding, so I can't review this any further, but review my update before saying it won't apply.  I gave the scenario that column `b` (any of your added columns) could have the same column `a` and same date.  You may have data/system constraints to prevent this from happening, but the query would still be what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure why you selected the answer that you did, but the above should do what you need, based on your previous question.  I'm trying not to answer your other question because I don't want to contribute to deleting "useless" records, since I believe no information is useless.  If you're having to extract data from a table, then you need to either 1) change your application or 2) change your database (adding triggers / logging), so that the information is placed where it needs to be.  I suggest using an `update` query and proper triggers/logs

Comment: vol7ron, well I did flag your answer as useful. Unfortunately I have to select a single 'correct' answer, in the spirit of SO. The answer given by Mike was very clear and the query was very easily understandable. Your query is more tedious, while both are correct. As simple as that. I avoid using features that I can do without using simply querying, and in my case simple querying without triggers and update worked. I also hence avoid extra queries. That is not to say your query is incorrect, I simply chose Mike' version after testing it fist.

Comment: So long as you got the answer.  `Select a,b from (select a,b from table order by b) as c group by a;` does not solve the problem, though.  BTW, you won't need this query if triggers are in place.  I'm just advocating good database design vs patching.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b
FROM tbl t
WHERE b = (SELECT MAX(b) FROM tbl WHERE tbl.a = t.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table user_payments
(
    phone_nr int NOT NULL,
    payed_until_ts datetime NOT NULL
)

insert into user_payments
(phone_nr, payed_until_ts)
values
(1, '2016-01-28'), -- today
(1, '2016-01-27'), -- yesterday  
(2, '2016-01-27'), -- yesterday 
(2, '2016-01-29')  -- tomorrow

select phone_nr, MAX(payed_until_ts) as latest_payment
from user_payments
group by phone_nr

-- OUTPUT:
-- phone_nr latest_payment
-- 1        2016-01-28 00:00:00.000
-- 2        2016-01-29 00:00:00.000
```

In the above example, I have used datetime column but similar query should work for timestamp column.

The MAX function will basically do the "ORDER BY" payed_until_ts column and pick the latest value for each phone_nr.
Also, you will get only one value for each phone_nr due to "GROUP BY" clause.