# SQL - SELECT DISTINCT and ORDER BY Latest

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I would like to select all distinct `gameName` records fomr my database. Currently I do this via the following SQL (simplified)

```
SELECT DISTINCT gameName FROM myTable ORDER BY gameName;
```

Table structure

```
id  | gameName   |  modified
__________________________________________
1     foo          2014-12-21 19:24:59
6     goo          2014-12-18 14:24:59
8     foo          2015-01-01 11:24:59
21    doo          2014-11-23 21:24:59
32    foo          2014-10-01 19:24:59
3     doo          2014-08-15 22:24:59
```

OUTPUT

```
doo
foo
goo
```

I am trying to modify this SQL to give me the distinct `gameName` with the latest `modified` date and then order by the latest `modified` date. I am not getting the results as I  would like.

Desired Output

```
foo          2015-01-01 11:24:59
goo          2014-12-18 14:24:59
doo          2014-11-23 21:24:59
```

If it makes any difference I am using `PDO`Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY` + `MAX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT gameName , Max(modified) as modified
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY gameName 
ORDER BY gameName;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this did it. I had tried `GROUP` with not much luck. The key part in this `sql` is `MAX(modifed)`.

Comment: `ORDER BY modified DESC`…

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer: [SQL: Any straightforward way to order results FIRST, THEN group by another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378049/sql-any-straightforward-way-to-order-results-first-then-group-by-another-colum#3378067)

It could look something like this. I do not have Access to an SQL Server so I can't test this right now. But it should give you an idea.

```
SELECT DISTINCT gameName FROM 
(SELECT gameName FROM myTable ORDER BY DESC modified)
ORDER BY gameName
```

Comment: mysql is not obliged to maintain order of a nested query. So your query is **NOT GUARANTEED** to return the desired result. Please check the other answer (which is ANSI SQL friendly) and drop your answer after. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that as I'm usually using a MS SQL Server

Comment: the same for SQL Server. Order of nested queries is **not guaranteed** in mysql, sql server, postgresql and oracle. Just because it works for you for a given case does not mean it will work some time after.