# SQL Subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I've found a few questions that deal with this problem, and it appears that MySQL doesn't allow it. That's fine, I don't *have* to have a subquery in the FROM clause. However, I don't know how to get around it. Here's my setup:

I have a metrics table that has 3 columns I want: ControllerID, TimeStamp, and State. Basically, a data gathering engine contacts each controller in the database every 5 minutes and sticks an entry in the metrics table. The table has those three columns, plus a MetricsID that I don't care about. Maybe there is a better way to store those metrics, but I don't know it.
Regardless, I want a view that takes the most recent TimeStamp for each of the different ControllerIDs and grabs the TimeStamp, ControllerID, and State. So if there are 4 controllers, the view should always have 4 rows, each with a different controller, along with its most recent state.

I've been able to create a query that gets what I want, but it relies on a subquery in the FROM clause, something that isn't allowed in a view. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
    ControllerID, TimeStamp, State
    FROM Metrics
    ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC)
AS t
GROUP BY ControllerID;
```

Like I said, this works great. But I can't use it in a view. I've tried using the max() function, but as per here: [SQL: Any straightforward way to order results FIRST, THEN group by another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378049/sql-any-straightforward-way-to-order-results-first-then-group-by-another-colum#comment3510988_3378063) if I want any additional columns besides the GROUP BY and ORDER BY columns, max() doesn't work. I've confirmed this limitation, it doesn't work.

I've also tried to alter the metrics table to order by TimeStamp. That doesn't work either; the wrong rows are kept.

Edit: Here is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of the Metrics table I am pulling from:

```
 CREATE TABLE Metrics (
  MetricsID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ControllerID int(11) NOT NULL,
  TimeStamp timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  State tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (MetricsID),
  KEY makeItFast (ControllerID,MetricsID),
  KEY fast (ControllerID,TimeStamp),
  KEY fast2 (MetricsID),
  KEY MetricsID (MetricsID),
  KEY TimeStamp (TimeStamp)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8958 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Create a new table from your query, add a trigger to keep it updated at whatever intervals you need,use that in a view

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer that you reference is incorrect, because it uses a MySQL extension that is explicitly documented not to return the results needed for the query to work:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the (strange) limitations of MySQL: you can't use a derived table (that's what you have there) in a view. You need to re-write the statement to not use a derived table.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the most recent row for each controller, the following is view friendly:

```
SELECT ControllerID, TimeStamp, State
FROM Metrics m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Metrics m2
                  WHERE m2.ControllerId = m.ControllerId and m2.Timestamp > m.TimeStamp
                 );
```

Your query is not correct anyway, because it uses a MySQL extension that is not guaranteed to work.  The value for `state` doesn't necessary come from the row with the largest timestamp.  It comes from an arbitrary row.

EDIT:

For best performance, you want an index on `Metrics(ControllerId, Timestamp)`.

Comment: Well, it certainly works. Thanks! I have a few questions though. First, is there any way to optimize this query? It takes a full 5+ seconds to run in a simple mysql prompt.
Second, why doesn't my initial query work? It orders all the results, then uses group by to start at the top (does it start at the top?) and pick out all the distinct controllerIDs. Every time I test it, it seems to work.

Comment: @Carrot . . . The ordering in the subquery has nothing to do (theoretically) with which arbitrary row is chosen for the value of `state` by the `group by`.  The value comes from an *indeterminate* row.  That means the `group by` is not guaranteed to affect it.

Comment: Awesome! I think I understand now. However, even with the index, the query still takes 3+ seconds to run. Is there anything I can do to optimize further? I feel like this isn't that intense of a query and shouldn't take quite so long to run.
Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Carrot . . . If you have a large table (with millions of rows), it might be hard to make an efficient view in MySQL.  That leads you down the path of a summary table maintained by triggers, which is pretty yucky.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Sorry, I misunderstood your question; I thought you were trying to overcome the nested-query limitation in a view.

You're trying to display the most recent row for each distinct ControllerID. Furthermore, you're trying to do it  with a view.

First, let's do it.  If your `MetricsID` column (which I know you don't care about) is an autoincrement column, this is really easy.

```
SELECT ControllerId, TimeStamp, State
  FROM Metrics m
  WHERE MetricsID IN (
              SELECT MAX(MetricsID) MetricsID
                FROM Metrics
               GROUP BY ControllerID) 
  ORDER BY ControllerID
```

This query uses `MAX ... GROUP BY` to extract the highest-numbered (most recent) row for each controller. It *can* be made into a view.

A compound index on `(ControllerID, MetricsID)` will be able to satisfy the subquery with a highly efficient [loose index scan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html).

The root cause of my confusion: I didn't read your question carefully enough.

The root cause of your confusion: You're trying to take advantage of a pernicious MySQL extension to GROUP BY. Your idea of ordering the subquery may have worked. But your temporary success is an accidental side-effect of the present implementation. Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Maybe I just don't see it, but I don't understand how this answers the question at all....

Comment: Duh, I misunderstood your question. Pls see my edit.

Comment: Okay, so I see how this works. However, it takes 9 seconds to run... I could work around it, but my Metrics table only has ~8500 rows. It'll probably have a whole lot more by the time I'm done with it.
I broke the query down, and each part runs very quickly by itself. Example: If I get all the max(MetricID)s with the subquery, then replace the subquery with those numbers `(SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Metrics ID IN (8562, 8567, 5478, 5532, 8568, 8569)`, it runs MUCH faster. Why is that? Is there any more optimization I can do?
Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Sorry for the double comment. I just did the following, and things seem to work very fast. I may have done something very dumb though...

First, I created a view with the subquery `SELECT MAX(MetricsID) MetricsID FROM Metrics GROUP BY ControllerID` Then, I created another view with the following: `SELECT ControllerID, TimeStamp, State FROM Metrics WHERE MetricsID IN (SELECT * FROM <tempView>)`

Does that work?

Comment: Your extra fast query time might be the result of caching. What is the performance of just the subquery?  What indexes do you have? Can you edit the question to include your table definition?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(MetricsID) MetricsID FROM Metrics GROUP BY ControllerID` runs in 0.0004 seconds, even after resetting mysql and running `RESET QUERY CACHE`. More than fast enough.
I think I created the following indexes: `(ControllerId, Timestamp)`, `(ControllerID, MetricsID)`,`(TimeStamp)`, and `(MetricsID)`

Comment: You now have some redundant indexes. That costs space and time on insertion.